# Small crack along windowsill

Tags: windows

I am decorating my new home and i've noticed a thin crack around the entire of the windowsill.

It is only visible if you are looking for it.

Is it something i need to get resolved or am i ok to fill it with something?

Comment: Photo would help.

Comment: I'll get a picture tonight.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, filler up with a finger swipe of caulk & see if it ever reappears. It's likely just a paint separation from temperature & humidity effects on different materials.